# grep -c not working

Tags: linux, bash, grep

*Using grep (GNU grep) 2.16*

I tried running `grep -Eo '<\/cite>' webpage` and get the following output

```
</cite>
</cite>
</cite>
</cite>
</cite>
</cite>
</cite>
</cite>
</cite>
</cite>
</cite>
</cite>
</cite>
```

Then I add the -c flag to count occurences `grep -cEo '<\/cite>' webpage` and get

```
3
```

Obviously the answer should be 13. Don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: With the content given, I cannot reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep -c` counts **lines matches**, while `-o` shows the match only. i.e. with input:

```
abcabc
abcabc
```

Using `grep -o 'a'` on the above will output:

```
a
a
a
a
```

And `grep -c 'a'` will give

```
2
```

You can pipe to `wc -l` to count number of matches:

```
$ grep -o 'a' demo.txt | wc -l
4
```